# RadComboBox show message if No Item is found after searching

Tags: c#, asp.net, scriptmanager, radcombobox, registerstartupscript

I have a RadGrid within which one of my columns is a GridTemplateColumn, which has a RadComboBox loading some items (the Edit mode is set to 'PopUp'). 
What I want is, if while searching for an item in the RadComboBox, no item is found, then give the user an option to add a new item. Currently, just for testing purposes, I want to be able to show a message if no item is found. This is what I have tried till now.

My RadComboBox within the RadGrid is defined as follows:

```
 <EditItemTemplate>
    <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="Product_PKRadComboBox" 
    ShowDropDownOnTextboxClick="false" ShowMoreResultsBox="true" EnableVirtualScrolling="true"
    EnableLoadOnDemand="true" EnableAutomaticLoadOnDemand="true" ItemsPerRequest="10"
    OnItemsRequested="Product_PKRadComboBox_ItemsRequested" AllowCustomText="true"
    Filter="StartsWith" DataSourceID="SqlProducts" DataTextField="ProductCode"
    DataValueField="Product_PK"></telerik:RadComboBox>
 </EditItemTemplate>
```

So I am checking my logic in the 'OnItemsRequested' event as follows:

```
 protected void Product_PKRadComboBox_ItemsRequested(object sender, RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        //RadComboBox combo = (RadComboBox)sender;

        if (e.EndOfItems && e.NumberOfItems==0)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "testMessage", "alert('Product Not Found. Do you want to add a Custom Product?');", true);
            //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "some_name", "if(confirm('here the message')==false)return false;");
        }
    }
```

I tried both lines of code within the IF Statement (which is checking if what the user typed in the RadComboBox exists or not, if it doesn't return any items, then show a message), but none of them seem to work. I tried the same in debug mode and set a Breakpoint on the line within the IF statement, it actually DOES execute but I cannot see the alert.

Answer (score 0):

I have just done something similar to this and my solution seems to be working pretty well.

Basically in ItemsRequested, once I know that no matches are found, I add a RadComboBoxItem manually. Give it a meaningful text such as "Add a new product..." and give it a distinct style as well to differentiate it from actual results.

Something like this:

```
protected void Product_PKRadComboBox_ItemsRequested(object sender, RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EndOfItems && e.NumberOfItems==0)
    {
        var addItem = new RadComboBoxItem("Add a new product...", "addnewproduct");
        addItem.ToolTip = "Click to create a new product...";
        addItem.CssClass = "UseSpecialCSSStyling";
        Product_PKRadComboBox.Items.Add(addItem);
    }
}
```

You then need to handle the SelectedIndexChanged event when the "addnewproduct" item is selected. Make sure to set the combobox's AutoPostBack="true".

```
protected void Product_PKRadComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{            
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value) && e.Value.Equals("addnewproduct"))
    {
        // do whatever you have to do to add a new product
    }       
}
```

You can use a RadWindow to show a confirmation box that says "Are you sure you want to add a new product?" with Yes and Cancel buttons. Go a step further by displaying the search text that the user typed in in a textbox within the RadWindow. This way the user can modify the text before adding the new item.

For example the user may type "water bottle" to search for a product. No results found so the user click on the "Add a new product..." item. The confirmation box shows up, then the user can change "water bottle" to "Green Durable Water Bottle 600ml" before clicking Yes to actually add the product.